# Trying to figure out a simple linear function

Tags: functions

Maximum input to function is $40$, minimum is $1$. Function works like this:

> $f(40)=0.2$, 
>   $f(1)=1$

we also want to know what $f(x)$ would produce. The answer would be "linear" to these two cases - for example, $f(20)$ would return something around $0.6$.

Can someone help me with this function?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is linear then $f(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b$. Plug in the values $x=1$ and $x=40$ to obtain $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thank you, this is the first, the shortest and the most universal answer and that's why I've chosen it. I'd like to thank the other two participants as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(1)=1$ and $f(40)=0.2$, and you want the function be linear, the output must decrease by $1-0.2=0.8$ units for every $40-1=39$ units of increase in the input. Therefore the output must decrease by $\dfrac{0.8}{39}$ units for every increase of $1$ in the input, and we have $$f(x)=1-\frac{0.8}{39}(x-1)=1-\frac8{390}(x-1)=1-\frac4{195}(x-1)\;.$$ If you want, you can simplify this to $$f(x)=\frac1{195}(199-4x)\;.$$

Comment: My calculations produced different constant, 199/195.

Comment: @dtldarek: *sigh* I really need to wake up. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1):

For linear $f$ we have $f(x) = a\cdot x + b$, so $0.2 = a \cdot 40 + b$ and $1 = a \cdot 1 + b$. [Solving](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5b0.2%3Da%2a40%2Bb%2C+1%3Da%2a1%2Bb%5d) this set of equations we have that $a = \frac{-4}{195} = -0.0205128$ and $b = \frac{199}{195} = 1.02051$.

Hope that helps ;-)